# <message><![CDATA[Please set an "image" parameter with image data for value]]></message>

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop

```
$image_url = $motos[0]->imageUrl;
$imgURL = urldecode($image_url);
$image_name = (stristr($imgURL,'?',true))?stristr($imgURL,'?',true):$imgURL;
$pos = strrpos($image_name,'/');
$image_name = substr($image_name,$pos+1);


/* Check the directory. Create if not exist*/
if (!file_exists('/tmp/img/')) mkdir('/tmp/img/', 0777, true);


/* Copy image to local temp*/
$ch = curl_init($image_url);
$fp = fopen('/tmp/img/'.$image_name, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);


/* Set the local image path*/
$image_path = '/tmp/img/'.$image_name;


/* Set the API URL for category*/
$url = PS_SHOP_PATH.'/api/images/products/46';
echo $image_path;


/* Upload image using CURL */
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY.':');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => '@'.$image_path.';type=image/jpeg'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I want to upload an image for my product with the webservice prestashop with an external link.
I don't know why i have this error because the image save in tmp/img is good.

I want to resolve the problem.

Comment: The `@filepath` syntax for file uploads is really outdated, you should rather be using https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php

Comment: https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/webservice/tutorials/advanced-use/image-management/#using-curl has an example, try and follow that as closely as you can.